# Replace text in file by using dic

Tags: python

There are 5404 in "noslang.txt". Example

```
...
2mz   tomorrow
2night   tonight
2nite   tonight
soml   story of my life
ssry   so sorry
...
```

In "test.txt"

```
ya right
i'll attend the class
2morow will b great
```

My codes:

```
 NoSlang = open("noslang.txt")
 for line in NoSlang:
      slang,fulltext = map(str, line.split('\t'))
      dic[slang] = fulltext.strip('\n')


 file = open('test.txt').read().split("\n")
 for line in file:
     sline = line.split(" ")
     for n,i in enumerate(sline):
         if i in dic:
             sline[n] = dic[i]
     print ' '.join(sline)
```

I tried to create dictionary and replace them in sentence from "test.txt". 
The results showed the same, nothing change.

Any suggestion?

Expected results:

```
 yeah  right
 i'll attend the class
 tomorrow will be great
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open('noslang.txt') as f:
    dic = dict(line.strip().split(None,1) for line in f)
...     
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:                                             
        spl = line.split()
        new_lis =[dic.get(word,word) for word in spl]
        print " ".join(new_lis)
...         
yeah right
i'll attend the class
tomorrow will b great
```

where `noslang.txt` contains:

```
ya   yeah
2morow   tomorrow 
2mz   tomorrow
2night   tonight
2nite   tonight
2nyt   tonight
```

Comment: or `dic = dict(line.strip().split() for line in f)`

Comment: My codes to create dic are working but I can not replace in sentence. I  tried your codes to create dic. I got error.

Comment: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required

Comment: @ThanaDaray it works fine for the file you've posted above, in fact I just tested your code to and got the correct output.

Comment: @ThanaDaray My code works fine and are you sure your file contains only 2 items per line?

Comment: Yes, two item. some like "soml \t story of my life"  First and second, they are separated by "\t"

Comment: @ThanaDaray ah! that's what I wanted to know. Fixed the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to substitute the words in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
from functools import partial

with open('noslang.txt') as file:
    # slang word -> translation
    slang_map = dict(map(str.strip, line.partition('\t')[::2])
                     for line in file if line.strip())

slang_words = sorted(slang_map, key=len, reverse=True) # longest first for regex
regex = re.compile(r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(map(re.escape, slang_words))))
substitute_slang = partial(regex.sub, lambda m: slang_map[m.group(1)])

with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print substitute_slang(line),
```

If `input.txt` is not very large you could replace all slang words at once:

```
with open('input.txt') as file:
    print substitute_slang(file.read()),
```

Comment: Safest to put longest match groups first: `'|'.join(sorted(map, re.escape, slang_map), key=len, reverse=True)` (etc... instead)

Comment: @JonClements: You're right. I've ordered slang words: longest first for the regex. Even more, in addition to short/long match overlap, previous code might have produced different results from run to run due to hash randomization.

Comment: @JonClements: though for slang words that are single words order shouldn't matter due to `\b` in the regex.